# Show that the Möbius band has its central circle $C$ as a deformation retract

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have started this problem by using the planar representation of the Möbius band and noted that a line down the middle is probably what is meant by the central circle, since travelling from top to bottom (where the left and right sides are identified in opposite directions) appears to trace out a circle.

The specifics of the deformation retraction are lost on me, I think I need a homotopy $f:M \times I \to S^1$ such that for all $m\in M$ and $x\in S^1$ we have $f(m,0)= m$, $ f(m,1)\in S^1$, $ f(x, 1) = x$.

Is there a parameterisation of the Möbius band that makes defining such a function explicitly obvious? Intuitively I can imagine pulling the sides of the Möbius band in continuously to the circle, is the idea of straight line homotopy useful here?

Comment: Actually, the map is $M\times I\to M$ and the condition is $f(x,t)=x$ for all $t\in I$.

Comment: I'm not seeing how these conditions will lead to a (edit:) deformation retraction?

Comment: I just corrected some formulas you wrote. The homotopy is from $M$ to $M$ and it is constant on $S^1$, that's why $f(x,t)=x$.

Answer (score 14):

A deformation retract of a space $X$ to a subspace $A$ is a continuous map $F : X \times [0, 1] \to X$ such that $F(x, 0) = x$, $F(x, 1) \in A$ and $F(a, t) = a$ for all $a \in A$, $x \in X$ and $t \in [0, 1]$.

To prove that the moebius strip deformation retracts onto the center circle, consider the fundamental square $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ with the two sides $\{0\} \times [0, 1]$ and $\{1\} \times [0, 1]$ identified oppositely via identification $(0, t) \sim (1, 1-t)$.

Construct a deformation retract of this square onto the center interval $[0, 1] \times \{1/2\}$ via the map $F((x, y), t) = (x, t/2 + (1-t)y)$. Next, doing the identifications on the deformation retracted $[0, 1] \times \{1/2\}$ gives the center circle $[0, 1] \times \{1/2\}/(0, 1/2) \sim (1, 1/2) \cong S^1$.

Comment: Your central circle is the line essentially tracing a path between the two identified sides, is this correct? I had imagined the central circle would be a line parallel to the identified sides in the fundamental square.

Comment: Ah, I had made a typo. See if this looks clearer now.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Shouldn't your center interval be $[0, 1] \times \{1/2\}$? Based on your map $F((x, y), t)$ it seems that your center interval is horizontal, not vertical.

Comment: @Coward Of course, thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just “pulling the sides in” works and it’s not hard to describe explicitly.

Parameterize the planar representation $P$ of the band below, where $-\pi\le x \le \pi$ and $-1\le y\le1$, and where $e$ (which you need not give explicitly) is any embedding of $P$ into $\mathbb R^3$ that’s one-to-one except two-to-one on the left and right sides ($e(-\pi,y)=e(\pi,y)$). In other words, $M=e(P)$. Note that for $X$ equal to the $x$-axis, $e(X)$ is a circle $S^1$.

[image]

For a point $m\in M$, where $m=e(x,y)$, define $f(m,i)=e(x,y(1-i))$. You can check that this satisfies the requirements.